# Can "more globalized companies" mean "more companies which are globalized"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Compared with their predecessors, today's CEOs are required to operate **more globalized companies**.

Are there two ways to interpret the phrase? Or it depends on the context?

Comment: Yes, it can be ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of your sentence, there is only one *logical* meaning. In isolation, this use of 'more' could be ambiguous.

For example:

> This company needs more experienced workers.

This could mean:

1. That the company needs more workers who are experienced (implies that it already has experienced workers, and needs more like them).
2. That the company needs workers who are more experienced (implies that the workers the company already has are not experienced enough, or that the subject under discussion is not experienced enough to work for the company).

One would hope the context would make that clear.

In your example, there is only one logical meaning. To be a CEO, one must already have a company. It wouldn't make sense to say a CEO should find more companies to run.

However, I'm not so sure about that implied meaning. I understand 'globalisation' to be a process and 'globalised' to be something that has completed that process. There may be gradations of globalisation, but personally, I don't like the term "more globalised". Are they globalised, or not? I would prefer:

> Compared with their predecessors, today's CEOs are required to operate their companies with a more global outlook.